# Can't construct std::function with brace initialization

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization, braced-init-list

EDIT: I was being dumb. The functionMaker call is shockingly a function not a constructor, so the braces obviously don't work.

So I have what is basically a factory function for producing a std::function from int to int, a quick minimal example is

```
std::function<int(int)> functionMaker(int x) {
    return [x](int foo){return foo*x;};
}
```

Basically, I want to bind some values into the function (kind of like currying), and then call it later.

I want to use it through something like

```
functionMaker{2}(10)
```

But it errors me.

I verified that

```
functionMaker(2)(10)
```

works

And I explored what happens if I stored the function and then called it.

```
auto fct = functionMaker{2};
std::cout << fct(10) << std::endl;
```

fails, but

```
auto fct = functionMaker(2);
std::cout << fct(10) << std::endl;
```

works.

So it seems like braces just don't work here. What's going on? To reiterate, I would like to call it with something like `functionMaker{2}(10)`. This way it's a bit easier for me to read which part is the construction and which part is the calling. What am I missing here?

Comment: ...damn. Wait I'm a moron.

Comment: Your title is incorrect.  You _can_ construct a std::function with brace initialization.  You simply can't designate a function call using those `{}` characters.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that it's just a function call. I got too wrapped up with the details that I somehow didn't realize that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like `functionMaker{}` to work, then `functionMaker` needs to be a class/struct. Functions can only take arguments via `()`. However, it's relatively easy to make it a class:

```
struct functionMaker
{
    functionMaker(int x)
    : f([x](int foo){return foo*x; }) {}

    int operator()(int foo) { return f(foo); }
    std::function<int(int)> f;
};
```

It's a bit more clumsy, but you only need to write it once; you can even generalize it to be like, `make_functionMaker(f, ...)`.

Note that you can save `std::function`'s overhead by simply implementing the function in `operator()`.

Comment: There is no need for a `std::function` member in this, it just makes it less efficient.  You can just do the logic of `f` in `operator()` and have a `int` member in the class for the value to multiply by.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I'm aware of that - but I'd like to make it as similar as possible to the version of OP. Nevertheless, I'll update with a small note on this.